# Misunderstanding repeat directive - it should fail, but doesn't

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I would like to write a grammar (highly simplified) with:

```
grr := integer [ . integer ]
```

with

```
integer ::= digit { [ underline ] digit }
```

Since the parsed literals are needed again later (the real grammar is more complex, not everything can be converted to a number immediately) the literal must be stored completely as string (more precisely as iterator_range) in the AST for later use (with underline).

The problem now is that the literal expressions can be longer than they should be (regarding the implementation/computation etc. later). The obvious solution is the `repeat` directive (here detailed for Qi [repeat](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/repeat.html) or very short for [X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/directive.html)).

This is where my problems start ([coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85823a3e229d68ba)):

```
    for(std::string_view const s : {
        // ok
        "0", "10", "1_0", "012345", 
        // too long
        "0123456",
        "1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0", 
        // absolutely invalid
        "1_2_3_4_5_6_", "_0123_456", ""
    }) {
        auto const cs = x3::char_("0-9");
        std::string attr;
        bool const ok = x3::parse(std::begin(s), std::end(s), 
            x3::raw[ cs >> x3::repeat(0, 5)[ ('_' >> cs) | cs] ],
            attr);
        cout << s << " -> " << attr 
             << " (" << std::boolalpha << ok << ")"
             << "\n";   
    }
```

gives

```
0 -> 0 (true)
10 -> 10 (true)
1_0 -> 1_0 (true)
012345 -> 012345 (true)
0123456 -> 012345 (true)
1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0 -> 1_2_3_4_5_6 (true)
1_2_3_4_5_6_ -> 1_2_3_4_5_6 (true)
_0123_456 ->  (false)
 ->  (false)
```

If the literal is too long, the parser should fail, which it does not. If it ends with an underline, it should do that too - but it doesn't. Underline at the beginning and empty literals are correctly recognized/parsed as false.

Meanwhile, I try to write the more complex parsers into a separate parser classes, but here I am e.g. missing the rule to recognize the literal ending with an underline....

Furthermore, BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG seems to be broken all of a sudden - there is no output.

What is the solution to my problem? I'm out of ideas except absolutely low-level and complicated via iterator, counter, etc.

This problem also affects other rules to be implemented.

Comment: "Furthermore, BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG seems to be broken all of a sudden - there is no output." - BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG debugs rules, but there are exactly zero `x3::rule` instances in your code.

Comment: Your original code with rules and debug output: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/891dfa52652ad53d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the literal is too long, the parser should fail

Where does it say that? It looks like the code does exactly what you ask: it parses at most 6 digits with the requisite underscores. The output even confirms that it does exactly that.

You can of course make it much more apparent by showing what was **not** parsed:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8464439db75c89af)**

```
auto f = begin(s), l = end(s);
bool const ok = x3::parse(
    f, l, x3::raw[cs >> x3::repeat(0, 5)[('_' >> cs) | cs]], attr);

fmt::print(
    "{:21} -> {:5} {:13} remaining '{}'\n",
    fmt::format("'{}'", s),
    ok,
    fmt::format("'{}'", attr),
    std::string(f, l));
```

Prints

```
'0'                   -> true  '0'           remaining ''
'10'                  -> true  '10'          remaining ''
'1_0'                 -> true  '1_0'         remaining ''
'012345'              -> true  '012345'      remaining ''
'0123456'             -> true  '012345'      remaining '6'
'1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0' -> true  '1_2_3_4_5_6' remaining '_7_8_9_0'
'1_2_3_4_5_6_'        -> true  '1_2_3_4_5_6' remaining '_'
'_0123_456'           -> false ''            remaining '_0123_456'
''                    -> false ''            remaining ''
```

### Fixes

To assert that a complete input be parsed, use either `x3::eoi` or check the iterators:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0609ebdaffcaea84)**

```
bool const ok = x3::parse(
    f,
    l,
    x3::raw[cs >> x3::repeat(0, 5)[('_' >> cs) | cs]] >> x3::eoi,
    attr);
```

Prints

```
'0'                   -> true  '0'           remaining ''
'10'                  -> true  '10'          remaining ''
'1_0'                 -> true  '1_0'         remaining ''
'012345'              -> true  '012345'      remaining ''
'0123456'             -> false '012345'      remaining '0123456'
'1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0' -> false '1_2_3_4_5_6' remaining '1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0'
'1_2_3_4_5_6_'        -> false '1_2_3_4_5_6' remaining '1_2_3_4_5_6_'
'_0123_456'           -> false ''            remaining '_0123_456'
''                    -> false ''            remaining ''
```

### Distinct Lexemes

If instead you want to allow the input to continue, just not with certain characters, e.g. parsing many such "numbers":

```
auto const number = x3::lexeme[ //
    x3::raw[cs >> x3::repeat(0, 5)[('_' >> cs) | cs]]
    // within the lexeme, assert that no digit or _ follows
    >> ! (cs | '_') //
];
```

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0b67a6a300f6801)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

namespace Parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    auto const cs = x3::digit;
    auto const number = x3::lexeme[ //
        x3::raw[cs >> x3::repeat(0, 5)[('_' >> cs) | cs]]
        // within the lexeme, assert that no digit or _ follows
        >> ! (cs | '_') //
    ];
    auto const ws_or_comment = x3::space | "//" >> *~x3::char_("\r\n");
    auto const numbers = x3::skip(ws_or_comment)[number % ','];
} // namespace Parser

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> attr;
    std::string_view const s =
        R"(0,
           10,
           1_0,
           012345,
           // too long
           0123456,
           1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0,
           // absolutely invalid
           1_2_3_4_5_6_,
           _0123_456)"sv;

    auto f = begin(s), l = end(s);
    bool const ok = parse(f, l, Parser::numbers, attr);

    fmt::print("{}: {}\nremaining '{}'\n", ok, attr, std::string(f, l));
}
```

Prints

```
true: ["0", "10", "1_0", "012345"]
remaining ',
           // too long
           0123456,
           1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0,
           // absolutely invalid
           1_2_3_4_5_6_,
           _0123_456'
```

### Proving It

To drive home the point of checking *inside the lexeme* in the presence of *otherwise* insignificant whitespace:

```
auto const numbers = x3::skip(ws_or_comment)[*number];
```

With a slightly adjusted test input (removing the commas):

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d1b6a04b8f42d5b)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

namespace Parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    auto const cs = x3::digit;
    auto const number = x3::lexeme[ //
        x3::raw[cs >> x3::repeat(0, 5)[('_' >> cs) | cs]]
        // within the lexeme, assert that no digit or _ follows
        >> ! (cs | '_') //
    ];
    auto const ws_or_comment = x3::space | "//" >> *~x3::char_("\r\n");
    auto const numbers = x3::skip(ws_or_comment)[*number];
} // namespace Parser

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> attr;
    std::string_view const s =
        R"(0
           10
           1_0
           012345
           // too long
           0123456
           1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0
           // absolutely invalid
           1_2_3_4_5_6_
           _0123_456)"sv;

    auto f = begin(s), l = end(s);
    bool const ok = parse(f, l, Parser::numbers, attr);

    fmt::print("{}: {}\nremaining '{}'\n", ok, attr, std::string(f, l));
}
```

Prints

```
true: ["0", "10", "1_0", "012345"]
remaining '0123456
           1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0
           // absolutely invalid
           1_2_3_4_5_6_
           _0123_456'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, well explained! After seeing your solution, I was ashamed of this since I've use lexeme and not operator at other places before. Basically, I didn't take care of the intended behavior after the count gets full ...

Comment: It's easy to miss. It's not far from the classical pitfall with [`std::regex_match` vs `std::regex_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match#:~:text=Because%20regex_match%20only%20considers%20full%20matches%2C%20the%20same%20regex%20may%20give%20different%20matches%20between%20regex_match%20and%20std%3A%3Aregex_search). No matter how oft-documented, people will still bring their own logical set of expectations, and only part of the people will happen to have the right expectations.

Comment: I don't think all these came natural to me. I've just been through the mill so many times that I spot them quicker by now.